# Sympy solve constant coefficient, first order linear difference equation with initial conditions

Tags: sympy

I am learning `sympy` and first order linear difference equations.

The solution is `y(n) = n^{2}*.25 + n*.625 + 0.28125*(1-(-3)^{n})` for the equation `y(n) = x(n)-3y(n-1)` with initial conditions `y(-1)=0` and `x(n) = n^{2}+n`.

I am stuck at solving, this is what I have:

```
from sympy import *
n, i = symbols("n i", integer=True) 
a, b = IndexedBase("a"), IndexedBase("b")
def x(n): return n**2+n
y = Function("y")

lexpr = y(n)
s1 = Sum(b[i]*x(n-i),(i,0,1)).doit().subs([(b[i], u) for i,u in enumerate([1., 0.])])
s2 = -Sum(a[i]*y(n-i),(i,1,1)).doit().subs([(a[1],3.)])
rexpr = s1 + s2
pprint(Eq(lexpr, rexpr))
diffeq = Eq(lexpr, rexpr)
res = dsolve(diffeq, ics={y(-1): 0})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `dsolve` but `dsolve` is for *ordinary differential equations*. Your equation is a *difference equation* or more precisely a linear recurrence. The `rsolve` function is for solving recurrence relations:

```
In [40]: diffeq
Out[40]: 
            2                       
y(n) = 1.0⋅n  + 1.0⋅n - 3.0⋅y(n - 1)

In [41]: rsolve(diffeq, y(n))
Out[41]: 
    n         ⎛     2              ⎞
-3.0 ⋅C₀ + C₀⋅⎝1.0⋅n  + 3.0⋅n + 2.0⎠
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.recurr.rsolve
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html#sympy.solvers.ode.dsolve